# Is there a latex symbol for glasses?

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a latex symbol for glasses (eye glasses...)? I can find symbols as fanciful as Marge Simpson, but no glasses. Do you know of any?

Comment: That is Unicode U+1F453 () so with a suitable font and xelatex or lualatex it is easy to use that character.

Answer (score 14):

You can build your own:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{Skin}{RGB}{221,188,135}
\newcommand\Glasses{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-2,0) circle [radius=1.5cm]; 
\fill[white] (-1.95,-0.1) circle [radius=1.2cm]; 
\fill (2,0) circle [radius=1.5cm]; 
\fill[white] (1.95,-0.1) circle [radius=1.2cm]; 
\fill
  (0,-4) --  
  (-1.9,-4) to[out=210,in=40]
  (-3,-6) -- 
  (3,-6) to[out=130,in=-30]
  (1.9,-4) --
  (0,-4)
  ;
\fill 
  (0.55,0) arc (0:180:0.55cm and 10pt) --
  ++(0,-10pt) arc (180:0:0.55cm and 10pt) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=1pt,fill=Skin]
  (-0.55,-10pt) arc (180:0:0.55cm and 10pt)
  to[out=-70,in=70]
  (1.5,-4)
  to[out=-110,in=-70]
   (-1.5,-4)
  to[in=-110,out=110]
  (-0.55,-10pt)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\Glasses
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You may use the symbol [U+1F453](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f453/index.htm). Here are some [fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f453/fontsupport.htm) for this. You can browse the fonts on your system by clicking [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%F0%9F%91%93%20-%20EYEGLASSES%20%28U%2B1F453%29).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1F453}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I suppose; I just made one with Segoe UI Emoji but yours look posher specs:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just add it and include mine as well. I will delete then. Your comment was faster than me. Thanks for the vote, though.

Comment: no, yours is fine:-)