# Eyeglasses as item bullet

Tags: macros, theorems, itemize, tikz-styles, enumitem

I would like to Customizing lists **itemize**  and title of theorem to looks like that :

[image]

as usual in order to Switch chip, size and color for itemize i use

- `\usepackage{pifont}` or we can use Math mode

Hhere is an example of changing item bullet using pifont :

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}

\newtheorem{focus}{{\Large \ding{46}}\ \textbf{Focus}}

\begin{document}

\begin{focus}
On donne ici les deux méthodes les plus courantes pour déﬁnir une suite.
\begin{description}
\item[(1)] \underline{Suite déﬁnie par une formule explicite qui dépend de $n: n=f(n)$}
\end{description}
On considère la suite de terme général $u_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}$
\begin{itemize}[font=\color{blue} \Large, label=\ding{46}]
\item glasses in the leftside of the First item ;
\item glasses in the leftside of the second item ;
\item glasses in the leftside of the third item.
\end{itemize}
\end{focus}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]
but what i really want is something like that :

[image]

- Does someone know any font that has this symbol. if not could you help me to draw it with tikz

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking here. It seems you are surprised that you get a picture of a pencil, when you think you are asking for a pair of glasses. The table clearly doesn't list a pair of glasses. How are the math symbols relevant? are you looking for a pair of glasses as a font-symbol? Might have a look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250511/is-there-a-latex-symbol-for-glasses

Comment: i'm not surprised i know that s pencil. btw  if possible i would like to have Pair of glasses as a symbol like the picture that i posted

Comment: @Educ: If the unicode character in the link by `runartrollet` does not work: I don't know any font that has this symbol. You have to use an image, most likely or draw it with `tikz`

Comment: Just to clarify, you are just asking about identification of that symbol?
btw, your code doesn't quite work, are you asking for help with getting it to work?

Comment: nope i'm asking for the identifiction of that symbol

Comment: The package `bclogo` has an eye.

Comment: @Thérèse i just checked and its useful too. thank you

Comment: @Thérèse: I saw that too, but I find that eye-symbol quite scary ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version with `\includegraphics`, using the glasses image of [HeYo](https://openclipart.org/detail/173095/eyeglasses), but of course, this will not change the colour!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\myfile}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{gozluk1-2400px}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={\myfile}]
  \item A one
    \item A two
      \item A three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{}

%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{break}

\newcommand{\myfile}[1][0.05]{%
  \includegraphics[scale=#1]{gozluk1-2400px}%
}


\newtheorem{focus}{\Large \raisebox{-0.2\baselineskip}{\mbox{\myfile[0.1]}} \textbf{Focus}}

\begin{document}

\begin{focus}
On donne ici les deux méthodes les plus courantes pour définir une suite.
\begin{description}
\item[(1)] \underline{Suite définie par une formule explicite qui dépend de $n: n=f(n)$}
\end{description}
On considère la suite de terme général $u_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}$
\begin{itemize}[font=\color{blue} \Large, label={\raisebox{-0.15\baselineskip}{\myfile[0.06]}}]
\item glasses in the leftside of the First item ;
\item glasses in the leftside of the second item ;
\item glasses in the leftside of the third item.
\end{itemize}
\end{focus}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Next update**

Use the `\faBinokulars` symbol from `fontawesome` -- it's not eyeglasses, but 'similar'

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{break}


\newtheorem{focus}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\faBinoculars}\ \Large\textbf{Focus}}

\begin{document}

\begin{focus}
On donne ici les deux méthodes les plus courantes pour définir une suite.
\begin{description}
\item[(1)] \underline{Suite définie par une formule explicite qui dépend de $n: n=f(n)$}
\end{description}
On considère la suite de terme général $u_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}$
\begin{itemize}[font=\color{blue}, label={\faBinoculars}]
\item glasses in the leftside of the First item ;
\item glasses in the leftside of the second item ;
\item glasses in the leftside of the third item.
\end{itemize}
\end{focus}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Educ: See the update please.

Comment: The `glasses` image should be shifted down for the item bullets too, in my point of view

Comment: could you fixed it please

Comment: @Educ: Done so (not updated the screen shot, however). For best performance, define a new list type to make this settings the default then. (No, this was not your question and I won't do it ;-))

Comment: it's okay for now i won't asked may be another day. Thank you so much for ur time

Comment: @Educ: I've updated with a `glasses` - like symbol

Comment: it's binoculars :) but looks fine thank you so much

Comment: And finally (?) Try to use `\rotatebox{-45}{\faChain}` (requires `graphicx` and `fontawesome` packages) ;-)

Comment: Apparently you've deleted the comment about accepting. You may accept it and if someone shows up with a better (tikz?) way, you can switch the acceptance to that post

Comment: Okay thank you i thought if i accepted people don't encourage to come up  with a better for example  tikz

Comment: @Educ: It's always possible to add an answer as an alternative (unless the question isn't closed for whatever reasons)

Comment: Ich bin Ihnen sehr dankbar für what you did .